# .NET 6 Single-File ASP.NET template with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-6.0

I am using the Visual Studio 2022/.NET 6 Razor pages template. It uses a top-level C# 10 program file. Program.cs looks something like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Data;
using Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var settings = builder.Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();

builder.Services
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

My DBContext looks like this

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    internal DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder){ /* ... */ }
}
```

When I run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration -v`, I get the following error:

```
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'Data'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Data.DatabaseContext.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Data.DatabaseContext.ApplicationDbContext'.
```

Visual Studio `Add-Migration` also fails to build, but provides no stack trace.

The [provided link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728) indicated that I might be able to add an implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` to contain some startup code that might work.

I created this class, but it also seems to do nothing.

```cs
public class ApplicationContext: IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    ApplicationDbContext IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<SanDiegoContext>.CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = MyStaticConfigurationBuilder.GetConfig();

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString: configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use EF Core in .NET 6 without building a `GetHostBuilder(string[])` method and a `Startup` class? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This issue (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27923) claims that the work to support top level statements has been done. But I can't see any other reference to what was changed.

Comment: if i understand correctly, the page [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) doesn't say you must have a `Startup` class delcared, it says *in either the same project as the derived DbContext or in the application's startup project*, here *startup project* means you set the project as the project to execute. you don't need use `ApplicationContext` somewhere, it will be automatically discovered and used.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with the following steps:

1. Rebuild the project.
2. Make sure I was using Visual Studio Command Line Tools with the right project
3. Install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` to my Web project
4. Make sure my project builds on its own with a standard `CTRL-B` or `dotnet build`

Then my startup looks like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Data;
using Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var settings = builder.Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();

builder.Services
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

and the migration attempts to scaffold as usual